# Does a Mauritian need a visa to visit Finland?

Tags: visas, visa-free-entry, finland, mauritian-citizens

I am from Mauritius and I am planning a trip to Finland. I am getting mixed answers when searching, so would like to know for sure if Mauritian citizens need a visa to visit Finland or not.

My stay will be around a week or two and I'll be flying in from London.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finland is part of the [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area), so the [visa policy of the Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area) applies.

Mauritius is on the [“Annex II” list of countries which are visa-exempt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Nationals_of_'Annex_II'_countries_and_territories_(visa_waiver_countries)), so citizens of Mauritius are allowed to enter the Schengen Area without a visa for tourism/business. There is a slight difference compared to the general 90/180 rule, but in your case it is not relevant, you can just go to Finland without worry.

This can also be check using [Timatic](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html), the tool used by airlines to determine what documentation is needed.

For Mauritius nationals visiting Finland, the results are:

> Passport required.
>
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid for a minimum of 3 months beyond the period of
>     intended stay.
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of Mauritius for a maximum stay of 3 months. (SEE NOTE 56246).
>
> NOTE 56246: The maximum stay is granted within 6 months.
>
> Additional Information:
>
> - Joint passports must include For details, click here
> - Valid visas in full, invalidated travel documents are
>     accepted if accompanied by a new travel document.
>
> Warning:
>
> - Passports and/or passport replacing documents issued more
>     than 10 years prior to date of travel are not accepted.
> - Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.

Comment: Confirmation from Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Finland: https://um.fi/documents/-/asset_publisher/caSu4obBG5lW/content/mauritius-matkustusasiakirjat-suomeen/385107